# Modify .cs (C#) web running file

Tags: c#

I have a few C# files that I'd like to modify which are running on a web server on a website.

Of course, If I make changes, and save, the page will return an error because it can not be modified while it is running (compiled).

Maybe there is a away to stop the executing or just compile the class and replace it?

In java for example, if i want to update a class for a web page, I would compile the .java file and then replace the .class one.

I'm not really sure what to do with C# , I'm sure there is something similar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) make changes 2) build 3) replace the website's /bin folder with your freshly compiled /bin folder 4) have a coffee

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887847/hot-unload-reload-of-a-dll-used-by-an-application

Comment: Are the .CS files in question in an App_Code folder?  If they are, you can simply modify them and the server will automatically recompile the files.  If not, they shouldn't be on the server as .cs files.